# @media only screen Vs. Iframe

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

So i have a bit of a predicamenyt. I have a link that displays in an iframe if viewed on computer, and in parent page if on mobile device.

If viewed on the mobile device i only want users to see the page in landscape. So, i have use the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#warning-message { display: none; }
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
    #wrapper { display:none; }
    #warning-message { display:block; }
}
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
    #warning-message { display:none; }
}
</style>

....

<div id="wrapper">
<!-- page -->
</div>
<div id="warning-message">
please turn to landscape
</div>
```

However, the problem comes in because of the iframe. If viewed on a computer the warning-message div is shown, not the wrapper content, despite the fact that the computer screen is landscape. I think this is because the iframe is portrait.

Does anyone know of a way to make it so that in non-mobile devices, only the wrapper div content is displayed, not the warning message (ie effectively treat all non-mobile devices as landscape)?

I hope the question makes sense.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with just CSS. Your assumption is correct that the iframe itself, if taller than wide, will also trigger the portrait orientation rules, since an iframe is essentially a sandboxed browser. You'll get the same result if you open it in a desktop browser that has 'portrait' sizing.

A workaround could be, since you're already detecting desktop/mobile browsers, to add a special GET-parameter to the URL when opening in an iframe, ie. add `?iframe=1` to the URL, and then in the code (or if need be even in JS) detect this parameter to add an extra class to your `html` or `body` elements. You can then use this extra class to extend the media query rules.

Having said that I'd heavily recommend against what you're doing right now - media queries are all about making web sites and applications more **dynamic**, not **restrictive**. Prohibiting your users from holding their device the way they want to is just going to cause complaints and irritation, unneeded if you just use the same media queries to implement an alternative layout or scale down the landscape content to fit into portrait if aspect ratio is really that important.